How to Manage Multiple Environment Configurations (Local/Dev/Test/Prod) in a .NET Web API with Docker and GitLab CI?
I am developing a .NET Web API and using Docker for containerization. I have multiple environments (local, dev, test, and prod), and I'm using GitLab CI for automated deployments.
Currently, I am using appsettings.json files along with docker-compose.yml for managing environment-specific configurations.
Here are a few approaches I'm considering:
1. Environment Variables (.env): Use .env files to pass environment-specific variables (like connection strings and API keys) to Docker during container startup.
2. Docker Compose Files: Create separate Docker Compose files or use overrides for each environment (e.g., docker-compose.development.yml, docker-compose.production.yml).
3. Configuration Files: Use different .json configuration files (e.g., appsettings.Development.json, appsettings.Production.json) and let .NET automatically pick the right one based on the environment.
4. GitLab CI Environment Configuration: Configure GitLab CI to use specific environment variables or Docker Compose files based on the deployment stage (development, testing, production).
Given that I am currently using appsettings.json and docker-compose.yml, what is the best way to efficiently manage these configurations across different environments while using GitLab CI for automated deployment? Any advice or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here's an advise from a DevOps Engineer working in a company, which has a .NET application. We are using configuration files (appsettings.Development.json, etc.) in combination with Docker Compose files. The appsettings contain the regular information and the compose files contain the sensitive ones. We are deploying with Gitlab CI using Ansible and Ansible Vault (sensitive vaules are encrypted w/ Vault in Jinja tempaltes). But the best approach should be the one that works for you and the one you yourself are capable of maintaining.

@KevinKopf Currently, we do not have a dedicated DevOps engineer in our company, so in addition to working on project development, I am also responsible for finding an efficient deployment solution. One challenge I am facing is that each time I create a new project, I need to set up numerous environment configurations. Furthermore, if any changes are required later, I must update these configurations across multiple projects, which can be quite time-consuming and challenging to manage.
